# Java application crashes when calling System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, cygwin, native

I've used cygwin to build a dll (which depends on some openssl libraries). Now I'm trying to load the dll using `System.loadLibrary`. But at that point the application just exits with return code `-1073740940`. 
There is no exception or information. The libraries path is set using `-Djava.library.path=path/to/library`.

Why is my application crashing without any errors? If there's an error in native code I'd get a message about that, right? And the only static variable I have for sure does not cause a crash.

**EDIT**

As it turns out, I can generalize this question: Are there any pitfalls when using cygwin to build a dll for the use in java?
Another thing I noticed is that loading the library sometimes causes an immediate exit and sometimes does not finish at all (it just keeps loading the library until I kill the application

Comment: I would suggest: start with a JNI tutorial and exactly follow each step. If that works with your env and cygwin; you know that there must a problem in your setup. If it doesn't work, then you learned something, too ;-) One starting point: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As it turns out, even loading a dll without any functions results in a crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a clean solution to use cygwin with java. I guess I'll have to build my dll using Visual C++.